# How to create golf ball with dips in each dips?

Tags: modeling

What is the fastest way to create a dipped golf ball ? What I call dipped golf ball is a golf ball with three dips in each dip.

[image: One per dip]
[image: Two per dip]

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TW7WwUfAYxM) in order to create a golf ball but I can't repeat the operation in each dip.

EDIT: to be clear, this is what I call a dip:
[image]

Comment: aka  a "dimple"....

Answer (score -2):

When you click the faces and press I key and nothing happens reason

[image]

Individual options is off

To **ON** u have to press again **I key**

[image]

And with the faces selected S to Scale

[image]

**A small preview of the ball**

[image]

Comment: How would you add one or three dimples within each dimple above?  Is what the question is asking.

Comment: @batFINGER he means that in each dimple face he wants 1 or 3 dimples extra

Comment: I appreciate the efforts for this tutorial but as others pointed out, it's not what I need.