# How to access triangle vertices and their attributes in shader nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, faces, shader-nodes

Is there a way to access the attributes of a triangle or face associated with the currently processed fragment? I see that we can get barycentric coordinates for each face using Geometry node -> Parametric output but I would like to further get for example and ID or at least color value or whatever attribute of each adjacent vertex.
I guess I can do something like using the Position output to get a world-space coordinates and then get the closest vertices to this but that's not ideal.
For example here:
[image]

I would like to also know that the barycentric coordinates of the red point are also corresponding to the vertices 1,4,3.

Comment: I've only managed to get [this far](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196566/35559)... with OSL.  From there, I guess you could get the UV coordinates at the triangle corners, and, from there, any of their function-of-UV, or baked, attributes.. but we need an _Attribute_ node that takes a coordinate input.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hmm nice approach! I will have to experiment with it a bit. Thanks!