# Golf Ball Texture Node!

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to draw an exploded view of a golf ball with texture applied. I've been playing around with these settings for a while and finally found a good bump map that mapped perfectly to my quad sphere (sub divided 3, with cast 1) It looked perfect.

Next step was splitting the ball and applying a solidify modifier and this is where things messed up again. The pattern no longer wraps properly and instead squishes down towards the bottom edge.

Prior to this step I had created one additional edge loop near the bottom and separated the parts so that I could shade the inside of the ball differently than the outside.

Any idea what could be causing this or how to rectify? Happy to hear any and all suggestions about a better workflow as well.

Thanks!

[image: node setup]

Edit_07.29
Per Joachim's request adding additional images of UV map with solidify modifier as well as evidence the wrap was correct prior to that change.

[image: uv wrap with solidify]

[image]

Comment: Maybe not exactly on-point.. but https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196566/35559

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your UV map? That will probably immediately clarify why the mapping changed.

Comment: Hey @Joachim sure here you go.https://imgur.com/a/hcVvBmC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the ball before deleting one half, uncheck auto texture space in object data:

[image]

After that, you may remove half of the ball, texture space will remain untouched

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was some unassuming option I had to select hidden somewhere. Thanks a ton :)